# Get selected Value in ListView c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I just want to get the selected item in my ListView.

This the XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="Musique" Background="#1874CD" BorderBrush="#68838B">
    <ListView x:Name="ListM" Width="Auto" Background="#D1EEEE" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MediaCollection}" Margin="-8,-0.877,-1,-2.925" SelectionChanged="ListM_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" >
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="Auto" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Name="IconImage" Source="{Binding IconUri}" Panel.ZIndex="2" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Titre" Width="auto" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Composer}" Header="Artiste" Width="70" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Length}" Header="Durée" Width="50" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" Header="Album" Width="70" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I insert item with this piece of code :

```
ListM.Items.Add(new ListGrid() { IconUri = imagemp3.Source, Title = Ftitle, Length = duration, Album = Falbum, Composer = Fcomposer });
```

I need to get these details (`Title`, `Length`, ...) when I select an item on my list. I've tried but had many issues and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SelectedItems :

SelectedItems is the set of selected rows,

If you want to get only the Title:

```
string age = ListM.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
```

If you want to get all the details :

ListM.SelectedItems[0] returns an object. You first need to cast it to its specific type before you can access its members. 
Create a Media class (Title, Composer...), then :

```
private void getSelectedIteminListView(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Media media = (Media)ListM.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

Don't forget to add the event :

```
ListM.DoubleClick += getSelectedIteminListView;
```

Comment: Thanks you ! But, where I need to add the event ?

Comment: @JimmyJames You can add it in your form's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the `SelectedItem` to your type:

```
private void ListM_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var listgrid = (ListGrid)ListM.SelectedItem;
}
```

But it seems you are mixing something. You are using DataBinding (`ItemsSource`) but you also manually add items.
Better you only use DataBinding by adding the items to `MediaCollection` in your ViewModel and bind the `SelectedItem` to another property in the ViewModel:

in XAML:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly listen to @M.REJEB

```
    private void ListM_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListGrid media = (ListGrid)ListM.SelectedItems[0];
        string age = media.Title;
        MessageBox.Show("Selected : " + age);
    }
```

And it works with this class :

```
    class ListGrid
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public string Composer { get; set; }
        public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource IconUri { get; set; }
    }
```